Reference for accelerated sum to compute the Meissel-Mertens constant
The Meissel-Mertens constant
$$ B_1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} - \log\log n\right) $$
has the series representation
$$ 
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
B_1 = \gamma + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log\zeta(n).
\end{equation}
 $$
Many years ago I accelerated $(1)$ to compute $B_1$ at high precision by summing the relation
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log(1 - x^n) = -x $$
with $(1)$ for $x = 1/p_i$ from $i = 1$ to $N$. This gives the identity
$$ B_1 = \gamma + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\big(p_i^{-1} + \log(1-p_i^{-1})\big) + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log\biggl(\zeta(n)\prod_{i=1}^{N}(1-p_i^{-n})\biggr).$$
Loosely speaking the term in the $\log$ is now closer to $1$ than with $\zeta(n)$ alone since $\prod_{i=1}^{N}(1-p_i^{-n}) \approx 1/\zeta(n)$.

I can't remember if I found this accelerated formula on my own or in the literature.
Is there a reference I can use to cite this formula?

did you see $(3)$ in the link you gave?

Yes, and that's a good point. If we let $N \to \infty$ in the formula in my question, we do get equation $(3)$. However there seems to be a 'sweet-spot' for the value of $N$. If $N$ is too small or too large the sum converges slower (implementation dependent values of $N$ course). For my implementation I used $N = 16$.

@mathworker21 But it's an interesting point. This series is a blend between equations $(7)$ and $(3)$ in the link I provided. When $N = 0$ we have equation $(7)$ and as $N \to \infty$ we have equation $(3)$.
